# How to merge two csv files without duplication one column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 csv files ,one contain( UserId,MovieId,Rating ) second contain(MovieId,title,genres).I want to merge them in one file without duplicate MovieId.I used union function but get me only one file.

```
 import sqlContext.implicits._
    import sqlContext._
    case class DataClass(UserId: Int, MovieId:Int, ratings: Double)
    val Data = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/rating.csv").map(_.split(",")).map(p => DataClass(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim.toInt, p(2).trim.toDouble)).toDF()
    case class DataClass2( MovieId:Int, title: String,genres:String)
    val Data2 = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/movieupdate").map(_.split(",")).map(p => DataClass2(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim, p(2).trim)).toDF()
    val merged=Data2.union(Data)
    merged.rdd
      .map(_.toSeq.map(_+"").reduce(_+","+_))
      .saveAsTextFile("/usr/local/spark/dataset/merged")
```

How to merge them correctly as UserId,MovieId,ratings,title,genres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to join two dataset. You can do simple left outer join.

This is code snippet that you can adjust to read from text files.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

case class DataClass(UserId: Int, MovieId:Int, ratings: Double)

case class DataClass2(MovieId:Int, title: String,genres:String)

val Data = spark.createDataFrame(
   DataClass(101,1,5)
:: DataClass(102,1,4)
:: DataClass(103,2,3):: Nil)


val Data2 = spark.createDataFrame(
   DataClass2(1,"Movie Title 1","Action")
:: DataClass2(2,"Movie Title 2","Sci Fi"):: Nil)

val MergedData = Data.join(Data2, Seq("MovieId"),"left_outer")
```

Data.show(3,false)

```
+------+-------+-------+
|UserId|MovieId|ratings|
+------+-------+-------+
|101   |1      |5.0    |
|102   |1      |4.0    |
|103   |2      |3.0    |
+------+-------+-------+
```

Data2.show(2,false)

```
+-------+-------------+------+
|MovieId|title        |genres|
+-------+-------------+------+
|1      |Movie Title 1|Action|
|2      |Movie Title 2|Sci Fi|
+-------+-------------+------+
```

Joined data set will be:

MergedData.show(20,false)

```
+-------+------+-------+-------------+------+
|MovieId|UserId|ratings|title        |genres|
+-------+------+-------+-------------+------+
|1      |101   |5.0    |Movie Title 1|Action|
|1      |102   |4.0    |Movie Title 1|Action|
|2      |103   |3.0    |Movie Title 2|Sci Fi|
+-------+------+-------+-------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can join it by the MovieId field, then select the data that you need and then distinct it.

```
val merged = Data2.join(Data, Data2("MovieId") === Data("MoviewId"), "left").select("Data2.*", "Data.*").distinct()
```

Comment: this error appear 
overloaded method value join with alternatives:   (right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],joinExprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,joinType: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>   (right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],joinExprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>   (right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],usingColumns: Seq[String],joinType: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>   (right: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_],usingColumns: Seq[String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: Yes,I try it after editing but there is error . cannot resolve 'Data2.*' give input columns 'UserId, MovieId, ratings, MovieId, title, genres'